# Getting strange numbers returned from a function in C

Tags: c

I have a couple of files:

evaluate_sin.c:

```
int evaluate_sin(int deg) {
    double j = deg_to_rad(deg);
    j = sin(j);
    printf("sin(%d) =  %d\n", deg, j);
    return j;
}
```

deg_to_rad.c

```
double deg_to_rad(int deg) {
    double rad = (3.14 * deg) / 180;
    return rad;
}
```

When I pass the "deg" variable (which is an integer) in my evaluate_sin function to deg_to_rad j is ends up as some random number like -90503293. Why is this?

Comment: Pretty sure a `double` and an `int` (`%d`) don't have the same bit-format for that print. Try `%f`

Comment: Can you use `%f` instead?

Comment: Can you post the function call too? So that atleast we can see the parameters.

Comment: shouldn't it be `%lf` ?? @WhozCraig :-P

Comment: Where do people get the idea that they can learn how to program without learning how to read the manual? Well, the manual or the stackoverflow comments that reproduce the manual :(

Comment: @Aniket Hell I dunno. I never use floating point in my day-to-day, much less print the things. I just knew it *wasn't* `%d` =P. Judging by the [chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) I don't think it matters, but it is probably better form as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that j is a double, not an integer

So`printf("sin(%d) =  %d\n", deg, j);` should be placed with `printf("sin(%d) =  %f\n", deg, j);`

Answer (score 1):

You've not declared `deg_to_rad()`:

```
extern double deg_to_rad(int deg);
```

before you use it.  Your code assumes it returns an `int` and converts that into a `double`.

You should have a header `degtorad.h`.

#### `degtorad.h`

```
#ifndef DEGTORAD_H_INCLUDED
#define DEGTORAD_H_INCLUDED

extern double deg_to_rad(int deg);

#endif /* DEGTORAD_H_INCLUDED */
```

(The header guards aren't 100% necessary in this example, but this is a good basis for more complex cases where the header guards are necessary.)

Then your program files include this header.  Somewhere along the line, you need to declare `evaluate_sin()` too; it could go into the same header.

#### evaluate_sin.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "degtorad.h"

double evaluate_sin(int deg)
{
    double j = deg_to_rad(deg);
    j = sin(j);
    printf("sin(%d) =  %.6f\n", deg, j);
    return j;
}
```

Note also the change in return type (`double` instead of `int`); it will return 0 unless you manage to pass in an exact odd multiple of π/2 (when it would return -1 or +1).  And also the change in the format for the `double` value (`%.6f` instead of `%d`, which would print an integer).

If you're using GCC, you need to turn on compilation warnings; at least `-Wall`.

#### deg_to_rad.c

```
#include "deg_to_rad.h"

double deg_to_rad(int deg)
{
    double rad = (3.14 * deg) / 180;
    return rad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

although `printf("%f", doubleValue)` is okay with doubles, I would still suggest keep it as simple as possible and use the way `scanf()` requires the `%lf` for doubles. This gives the program sense of consistency.

so yes I would suggest:

`printf("sin(%d) = %lf\n", deg, j);`

Comment: This is OK if you're sure you have a C99 compiler.  Using `%lf` with C89 invokes undefined behaviour, which is never a good idea.  And, of course, the premier 'stuck in a time-warp' compiler is Microsoft's C compiler, which is a C89 compiler with very few of the C99 enhancements.  It is possible that MSDN defines the behaviour of `%lf` for MSVC, but be cautious.